# CEWP with Calendar New Form : hidding selections, setting all day by default

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, jquery, form

So I came across a cool trick first in a book, then on a blog ([here!](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/jquery-to-the-rescue-automate-all-day-event.aspx)), but it doesn't work for me. It's straightforward enough, couple lines of javascript/jquery, and a cewp in order to auto-select all day events, hide that as well as workspace and recurrence. Would this be caused by changes to jquery version since this is a bit dated? As I am using v1.7+ and this blog post
 shows reference to the 1.2.6 jquery cdn? Otherwise I can't figure it out??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('td.ms-dttimeinput').hide();
  $('span[title=All Day Event] > input').attr("checked","checked"); 
  $('tr:has(span[title=Recurrence])').not('tr:has(tr)').hide(); 
  $('tr:has(span[title=All Day Event])').not('tr:has(tr)').hide();
  $('tr:has(span[title=Workspace])').not('tr:has(tr)').hide();
});
</script>
```

again my jquery reference is v1.7.1a which is in a doc library versus cdn. The post shows 1.2.6? Am I on the right track? Would changes to jquery be what is preventing me from getting this to work, and if so does anyone know the relative change?

I am sure that it is either this, or something I am doing wrong here, because JBH is the man and lots of his information has helped me out quite a bit!

thanks as always guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out, so here is what I used in case someone else is looking for a solution to this as well:

Below is what worked to hide a field for something like a id. So if I was passing an ID to the form through a query string, then I could hide the field containing the value from the user. Added this to the form by CEWP:

```
<script src="/sites/DevCollection/Style%20Library/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("input[value='Save']").hide();
       $("table.ms-formtoolbar tr:first").hide();
       var fldItem = $("select[title='ParentID']");
       fldItem.hide();
</script>
```

same idea allowed me to hide calendar items on form, or really any field on any form.